# How to get a normal context menu on webpages that use custom context menus?

Tags: macos, mouse, context-menu, web, right-click

How do I get a normal context menu on a webpage that uses custom context menu(s)?

For example, Gmail uses custom context menus:

[image]

If I want to get a regular browser/system right-click menu, how would I do that?

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: On Windows with Firefox <shift><right click> brings up the regular menu.